# Having issues with parameters in my PHP code, parameters not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to build a form to add items to a database, but every time i click 'submit' it throws an error, and im having trouble spotting what is wrong.

The code i'm working with, its throwing an error for line 52, which has '));' and i've tried to change it around with no luck. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Error message 'Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // Field validation
    if(strlen($_POST['groupname']) == ''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter group/individual name';
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['address1']) == ''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter first line of address';
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['city']) < 2){
        $error[] = 'City field too short.';
    } 
    if(strlen($_POST['postcode']) < 7){
        $error[] = 'Please enter valid postcode.';
    }
    if(strlen($_POST['phone']) < 11){
        $error[] = 'Please enter valid contact number.';
    }
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    } else {
        $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT email FROM groups WHERE email = :email');
        $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!empty($row['email'])){
            $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
        }


        //If no errors - proceed
        if(!isset($error)){

            try {

                //insert into database with a prepared statement
                $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO groups (groupName,address1,address2,city,postcode,phoneNumber,email,coOrdinator)
                                VALUES (:groupname, :address1, :address2, :city, :postcode, :phone, :email, :co-ordinator)');
                $stmt->execute(array(
                                     ':groupname' => $_POST['groupname'],
                                     ':address1' => $_POST['address1'],
                                     ':address2' => $_POST['address2'],
                                     ':city' => $_POST['city'],
                                     ':postcode' => $_POST['postcode'],
                                     ':phone' => $_POST['phone'],
                                     ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                                     ':co-ordinator' => $_POST['co-ordinator']
                                     ));

                if ( $stmt ){
                    echo "<p>Kit has been added successfully!</p>";
                } else {
                    echo "<p>Sorry, there has been a problem adding the item.</p>";
                }


                exit();

                //else catch the exception and show the error.
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                $error[] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placeholders can't have hyphens in them, they have the same syntax as SQL identifiers (except for the `:` prefix). Change `:co-ordinator` to `:coordinator`.

Comment: Thanks alot! Definately wont forget that in future!

Comment: you can use underscores though. Which ever parameter naming strategy you use try to make sure its unique to only those parameters and used globally it will ease in reading the code. It goes for all attributes, methods etc you don't have to follow a coding standard. its not recommended but as long as you are consistent you can make your own standard.